# Spring boot, Caffeine cache as token store, refresh and evict

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, caffeine

I am currently using the **caffeine as JWT token store** in spring boot application. **Token expiry period is set to 30 minutes**. So I proactively wanna fetch a token before 30 mins and reload the cache, so that subsequent requests get a fresh token.

Following is my cache configuration:

```
cache:
  cache-names: token-service
    caffeine:
      spec: maximumSize=2,expireAfterWrite=30m
```

Following is my spring @Cachable, which is used by other spring services to get the cache and then query the external APIs which require the token.

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = { TOKEN_SERVICE_NAME }, key = "#root.target.EXTERNAL_API_TOKEN_SERVICE_KEY")
public Token getToken() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {...}
```

But intermittently API requests are getting "Not authorized (401)" which means token is invalid. As per my understanding, the cache loading will be blocked when it is evicted and till when the entry is reloaded again.

Does caffeine block threads internally till entry is loaded? I have read that Spring @Cachable does not wait for blocking. I have read about **sync=true** option in @Cachable and looking to **add the refreshAfterWrite** option to the cache configuration.

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = { TOKEN_SERVICE_NAME }, key = "#root.target.EXTERNAL_API_TOKEN_SERVICE_KEY", sync=true)

cache:
  cache-names: token-service
    caffeine:
      spec: maximumSize=2,expireAfterWrite=30m,refreshAfterWrite=29m
```

Also looking at using Cache preparation using @Bean rather than using the Cacheable. Any pointers towards **usage as above** and about **sync and refreshAfterWrite** operation in the context is highly appreciated.

Comment: I believe `sync` means it loads through the cache (e.g. `computeIfAbsent`) rather than around it (e.g. `get`, load, `put`). The latter is subject to cache stampedes by performing redundant work. If correct, then block block the caller when retrieving the value on a miss.

Comment: Unfortunately, `refreshAfterWrite` is not compatible with Spring Cache since it does not provide the loading function to the cache. This feature would reload asynchronously if a read occurs after that time period, but only if before the expiration time. That is a latency hiding technique for popular entries while allowing idle ones to expire. If instead you want entries reloaded regardless of activity, then using a scheduled task is the simplest option.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I will be trying the scheduler option.